# Convert C# ObservableCollection sample to VB.NET dataset or equivalent

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, binding

I have a C# example that is populating a multiselect combobox.  This was from an example found online.  It works fine with the static values coming from the observable collection.

I want to change this to be database driven from a SQL Server backend, but was having issues.  I did get it to populate the combobox, but the selection is acting kind of screwy.  Here is the sample code if anyone could help.  Some type of simple query from a Northwind table would suffice such as: "Select CategoryName from Categories".

So the question is: how to convert this ObservableCollection to use a query from a database rather than the static string list used in the example below? while implementing the same property changed functionality.

```
class DataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    private ObservableCollection<string> _animals = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Cat", "Dog", "Bear", "Lion", "Mouse", "Horse", "Rat", "Elephant", "Kangaroo", "Lizard", "Snake", "Frog", "Fish", "Butterfly", "Human", "Cow", "Bumble Bee" };

    public ObservableCollection<string> Animals
    {
        get { return _animals; }
    }

    private string _selectedAnimal = "Cat";
    public string SelectedAnimal
    {
        get { return _selectedAnimal; }
        set
        {
            _selectedAnimal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAnimal");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedAnimals;
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedAnimals
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedAnimals == null)
            {
                _selectedAnimals = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Dog", "Lion", "Lizard" };
                SelectedAnimalsText = WriteSelectedAnimalsString(_selectedAnimals);
                _selectedAnimals.CollectionChanged +=
                    (s, e) =>
                    {
                        SelectedAnimalsText = WriteSelectedAnimalsString(_selectedAnimals);
                        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAnimals");
                    };
            }
            return _selectedAnimals;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedAnimals = value;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedAnimalsText
    {
        get { return _selectedAnimalsText; }
        set
        {
            _selectedAnimalsText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAnimalsText");
        }
    } string _selectedAnimalsText;


    private static string WriteSelectedAnimalsString(IList<string> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
            return String.Empty;

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(list[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(", ");
            builder.Append(list[i]);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gabe: I updated it.  I want to use a SQL query rather than a static string list.  So basically can the ObservableCollection be populated from a DB query?  If not, how to make the example above work from a SQL query in another way.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a wrapper around a DataSet which implements INotifyCollectionChanged, so it can be dropped-in to replace an ObservableCollection.  That would be hard to do with a DataSet directly, since DataSet doesn't really have much of an event model, but it could work if you go directly to a DataTable within the DataSet, since it does have RowChanged, etc. events.

Comment: When do you expect the `ObservableCollection` to change?

Comment: Are you reading the question?  The example is using an OC.  I am looking for a way to bind the multi select combobox to a dataset or datatable based on a SQL query.  Whether the final result uses an OC or not is irrelevant, unless of course an OC is the only way to achieve this... That is what I am asking.

Comment: This would be used with a custom control (A combobox with an embedded listbox).  This would allow multiple selections within a combobox.  The sample project can be found at: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MultiComboBox.aspx.  I am trying to use this same object, only loaded from a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, but ...

Have you considered using LINQ with a Data Entity?

Add an ADO.NET Data Entity Model to your project and use the Wizard to connect to your data source.

Then write a LINQ statement that selects the columns you wish from the Entity object and set this as the ItemSource

Example:

```
myDataEntity Context = new myDataEntity();

List<Animals> myAnimals = new List<Animals>();
myAnimals = Context.Animals.ToList;

var myItemSource =
        from a in myAnimals
        select new { SelectedAnimal = a.animal, SelectedAnimalText = a.animaltext };
```

The LINQ select statement creates an anonymous type containing two fields as columns if set as the ItemSource i.e: SelectedAnimal and SelectedAnimalText

Now just set the ComboBox's ItemSource property

```
ComboBox.ItemsSource == myItemSource;
```

And you're done!